# Computer makes home network stop functioning

Tags: networking

Last week i reinstalled Windows 10. I started working with *Virtualbox* and an *Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS*. Last few days often when i turn on my computer the network stops functioning for all devices. Usually after a few modem+router resets i get back up and running. I removed Virtualbox and all port forwarding. The problem still persists. My mind is blown.

Comment: How are you connected? Wireless/wired?

Comment: Connected with wire.

Comment: What kind of system is it? Generally speaking when that happens on a wired connection it's because of a couple of oddities; the driver or firmware might be messed up, causing a weird packet to be sent to the network that messes up the whole system or the network card itself is sending too high (or low) a voltage to the router/switch and can pass that voltage along the line causing the equipment to malfunction. If a driver/firmware update doesn't fix it, you'll probably have to change the wired network card.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you txtechhelp for the informative help. I didn't have network drivers installed. My motherboard is the x99s sli plus from MSI. Just installed the driver and it's working again. Also turned on 100Mbps full on instead of negotiable in the BIOS and browsing feels allot faster :)